# AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'guild_icon'

Tags: discord, pycord

I am trying to set up a command to print the information of the server the bot is in. The code below gives the error  `AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'guild_icon'`

```
@commands.command()
async def serverinfo(self,ctx):
    name = str(ctx.guild.name)
    description = str(ctx.guild.description)

    owner = str(ctx.guild.owner)
    id = str(ctx.guild.id)
    region = str(ctx.guild.region)
    memberCount = str(ctx.guild.member_count)


    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=name + " Server Information",
        description=description,
        color=discord.Color.blue()
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(ctx.guild_icon)
    embed.add_field(name="Owner", value=owner, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Server ID", value=id, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Region", value=region, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Member Count", value=memberCount, inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

When trying to find the solution I tried to change the code to be

```
@commands.command()
async def serverinfo(self,ctx):
    name = str(ctx.guild.name)
    description = str(ctx.guild.description)

    owner = str(ctx.guild.owner)
    id = str(ctx.guild.id)
    region = str(ctx.guild.region)
    memberCount = str(ctx.guild.member_count)


    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=name + " Server Information",
        description=description,
        color=discord.Color.blue()
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(ctx.guild.icon)
    embed.add_field(name="Owner", value=owner, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Server ID", value=id, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Region", value=region, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Member Count", value=memberCount, inline=True)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

But then I get the error `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: set_thumbnail() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Could someone tell me what I have done wrong and point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem 1

ctx.guild_icon does not exist, you fix this in your second code by using ctx.guild.icon

### Problem 2

discord.Embed.set_thumbnail takes in a named argument for the image.

In fact, it doesn't take in an image at all, but rather a url

### Solution

To solve your issue, you should use the following:

```
embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon.url)
```

### More info

[discord.ext.commands.Context](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/ext/commands/api.html#context)

[discord.Embed.set_thumbnail](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.Embed.set_thumbnail)